# tooltip overlay not disappearing when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am very new to jquery and am running into a bug. Whenever I hover over a button on my page, it brings up a small tooltip. When I move the mouse, it disappears. However, if I click the button, the tooltip gets stuck and Im not sure why. It just stays there until I reload the page. Here is the code:

## _controls.html.erb

```
    <%= link_to 'Abandoned', priority, :class => 'abandoned', :'data-status' => 'abandoned',
                            :title => 'Mark as ABANDONED', :rel => 'tipsy' %>
    <%= link_to 'New', priority, :class => 'new', :'data-status' => 'new',
                            :title => 'Mark as NEW', :rel => 'tipsy' %>
    <%= link_to 'Started', priority, :class => 'started', :'data-status' => 'started',
                            :title => 'Mark as STARTED', :rel => 'tipsy' %>
    <%= link_to 'Completed', priority, :class => 'completed', :'data-status' => 'completed',
                            :title => 'Mark as COMPLETED', :rel => 'tipsy' %>
</div>
```

## part of priority jquery js file

```
...
jQuery.fn.priority = function()
{
    var priority = this;

    priority.bind('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        priority.selectPriority();
    });

    priority.bind('unselected', function() {
        priority.find('a.more').tipsy('hide');
    });

...

jQuery.fn.selectPriority = function()
{
    $('.priority.selected').not(this).unselectPriority();
    this.addClass('selected');
};

jQuery.fn.unselectPriority = function()
{
    this.triggerHandler('unselected');
    this.removeClass('selected');
};
```

any ideas why the tooltip overlay isn't disappearing after the button gets clicked?

PS I didn't write this code I am just trying to debug it. Let me know if this isn't the right code for where the tooltip is located.

UPDATE: the tooltip only gets stuck sometimes. I removed event.stopPropagation(); and it still happened.

Answer (score 2):

you could try take out the bind and invoke the tipsy hide directly in the event, like this: `$('#element').tipsy('hide')` which might help you debug it. I had the same problem in some of my stuff and calling hide solved it. Check out 'Manually Triggering a Tooltip' on the tipsy page: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Another option is to use the delayOut function on the element, like this:

```
 $('.mg-unrd').tipsy({gravity:'s', delayIn: 10, delayOut: 5});
```

The delayOut worked for me better than hide, which still gave me ghosts on occasion.

Actually, I've found this bit of code which solved it for proper...In the Tipsy.js file, around line 170, I added a mousedown to the eventOut, hooray!

```
//eventOut = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'blur';
eventOut = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mousedown mouseleave' : 'blur';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the snippets of code you've provided, but try commenting out the event.stopPropagation(); line and see what that does.

Comment: is there something else I can provide to make it easier to debug? also, I can't even tell where in the code the tooltip gets triggered...am I missing something? i've looked everywhere